# TeamCity Agent - AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, teamcity, aws-cli

I have deployed TeamCity server and Agent to AWS using JetBrains Stack Template (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/running-teamcity-stack-in-aws.html)

All seems to be good, my server starts, agent is functional, I have created several builds, etc.
I came to a point, where I want to deploy my application to AWS environment using aws-cli commands.

I am struggling to enable/install aws-cli into agent. My build steps are erroring out with `aws: command not found`
Does anyone have any ideas?
My progress so far: I have connected to agent EC2 machine via ssh bastion ec2, and I am able to invoke `aws --version` as ec2-user, but the build agent cannot see aws.

Comment: What permissions does a user need to be able to run the AWS-CLI and do the deployments? And what user is your agent running under?

Comment: @Nanhydrin sorry for my ignorance, but how do I check what user is my agent running under? I believe the agent has enough permissions to deploy application (apart from lack of aws-cli), since it is able to build the code just fine.

Comment: I think agent is running inside of docker container, therefore it is not able to "see" local aws installation. But I might be wrong..

Comment: I'm afraid I haven't a clue about Docker, or AWS to be honest, I'm just going on usual TeamCity Agent behaviour when it can't do something you can. I wouldn't assume that the fact it can build means it can deploy though. What exactly are you expecting it to do during the deployment? Spin up new Dockers instances?

Comment: I want it to buld a docker image with "docker build" command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out, my TeamCity agent runs in AWS ECS via docker image https://hub.docker.com/r/jetbrains/teamcity-agent

What I ended up doing is creating my own docker image by using jetbrains one as a base.

I uploaded my docker image to AWS ECS Repository. Afterwards I created a new revision for original task definition. This new revision uses my image instead of original one, therefore I have aws-cli there.

I then added my AWS profile to EC2 host machine and added volume to docker container (via task definition) so that container would be able to access .aws/credentials file.

Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM jetbrains/teamcity-agent

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python-pip
RUN pip install awscli --upgrade --user
ENV PATH="~/.local/bin:${PATH}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the aws-cli in team city agent using remote desktop connection as I used window agent of team city. In the build steps I used Runner Type as command line and executed the aws commands.

for more information you can refer below link where I answered the question:
[How to deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk on successful Teamcity build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24954695/how-to-deploy-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-on-successful-teamcity-build/55282935#55282935)